# Using per-column compression codec in Parquet.write_table

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I have pyarrow 2.0.0 installed. The [docs for `pyarrow.parquet.write_table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html) state

> compression (str or dict) – Specify the compression codec, either on a general basis or per-column. Valid values: {‘NONE’, ‘SNAPPY’, ‘GZIP’, ‘LZO’, ‘BROTLI’, ‘LZ4’, ‘ZSTD’}.

Works fine if `compression` is a string, but when I try using a dict for per-column specification, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong? I can use a similar dict for `compression_level` on a per-column basis without error.

```
(py3) C:\tmp\python>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> import pyarrow.parquet as pq
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['foo','bar','baz'])
>>> t = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
>>> pq.write_table(t,'test1.pq',compression=dict(foo='zstd',bar='snappy',baz='brotli'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py", line 1717, in write_table
    with ParquetWriter(
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py", line 554, in __init__
    self.writer = _parquet.ParquetWriter(
  File "pyarrow\_parquet.pyx", line 1390, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetWriter.__cinit__
  File "pyarrow\_parquet.pyx", line 1236, in pyarrow._parquet._create_writer_properties
  File "stringsource", line 15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

Comment: That seems a bug in `pyarrow`, I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10482 to track this. I don't think there is direct workaround for the released version .. (the bug is in the cython code).

Comment: thanks! Is there a user mailing list for Apache Arrow / pyarrow / parquet? I found only dev@arrow.apache.org and that seems aimed at developers of Arrow-related projects

Comment: Yes, there is also a user@ mailing list, see https://arrow.apache.org/community/